# Managing the number of active sessions in my Oracle Apex application

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I am attempting to control the amount of simultaneous connections in my Apex application.
(I'm working with Apex 18.2 and Apex 23.1)

I've looked for a native feature in order to achieve that, but the only thing I've found that could help me with my problem is using the WWV_FLOW_SESSIONS$ table, which record each connection to my application.
This table is updated at every connection and purged hourly by a job (ORACLE_APEX_PURGE_SESSIONS).
I could check this table during the authentication process (which works), but to make it efficient, I would have to change the recurrence of the purging job, but I'd rather not touch an Apex Job.

Is there a setting that I am missing or is there a more efficient way to control those sessions?
I'm happy to discuss this topic and provide information.

Comment: Just being curious: **why** do you care about number of active sessions? Do you experience any problems? Which ones? As of your **question**: as you already found out that Apex automatically purges sessions, could you then create your own scheduled job which does exactly the same, but every e.g. 5 minutes?

Comment: Plus, 99.9% of users never actually hit the logout button to end their session.  They just close the browser tab.  If you have a session timeout limit of, say, 60 minutes, that session that's been idle for 55 minutes is almost certainly abandoned.  But someone might come back to the tab where it's open.  Telling someone they can't log in now because they closed their browser tab without logging out 30 minutes ago seems very user hostile.

Comment: @Littlefoot I don't experience any technical problem but I would like to control the number of simultaneous connections for administration purposes.
Thanks for your suggestion, after more testing I've tried to call the purging function at the launch of the login page, which is promising.
There are however still some problems regarding the idle sessions, such as JustinCave mentioned.

Comment: @JustinCave thank you for this observation.
I've though about the problem, I might create a copy of the WWV_FLOW_SESSIONS$ table in order to prevent the same user being blocked by looking in the table if he was previously logged. I also discovered that after logging out, the "USERNAME" is update to "nobody", so this should prevent that scenario.

Comment: But the *vast* majority of users never bother to explicitly log out.  If I log in, do 5 minutes of work, and then just close the browser tab (normal user behavior), the session is still active from APEX's perspective.  I as a normal user have no idea how to get back into that session.  If you stop me from logging in again, that is going to be incredibly annoying to the vast majority of users.  I'm not sure what administration purposes are served here.  Are you trying to limit resource consumption?